# Can reflected gradients be turned into CSS?

Tags: css

I'm wondering if [this "reflected" gradient](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16248781/gradient.jpg) could be turned into CSS and how I would do that?

[image: Orange Reflected Gradient]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#753017+0,f48413+50,753017+100;Custom)?

```
background: #753017; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #753017 0%, #f48413 50%, #753017 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#753017), color-stop(50%,#f48413), color-stop(100%,#753017)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #753017 0%,#f48413 50%,#753017 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #753017 0%,#f48413 50%,#753017 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #753017 0%,#f48413 50%,#753017 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #753017 0%,#f48413 50%,#753017 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#753017', endColorstr='#753017',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: exactly :) thanks forgot about gradient generator